# Questions about Tuples

Tags: tuples

So I was able to run part of  a program doing below (using tuples)

```
def reverse_string():

  string_in = str(input("Enter a string:"))
  length = -int(len(string_in))
  y = 0
  print("The reverse of your string is:")
  while y != length:
    print(string_in[y-1], end="")
    y = y - 1


reverse_string()
```

The output is:

```
Enter a string:I Love Python
The reverse of your string is:
nohtyP evoL I
```

I am still thinking how for the program to reverse the position of the words instead of per letter.

The desired output will be "Phython Love I"
Is there anyway that I will input a string and then convert it to a tuple similar below:

So If I enter I love Phyton, a certain code will do as `variable = ("I" ,"Love", "Python")` and put additional codes from there...

Newbie Programmer, 
Mac

Comment: Though Your question looks ok, I suggest you to try to do something and post it once you reach a point where you can't move further. One idea is you can break the string using spaces and then loop over the array and reverse the individual words and the add the array into string again.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that I ran out of idea easily...thanks for the input, for Ronen Botzer, thanks for the "improved formatting" review.....thanks guys!